# Import data from tr balise with python

Tags: python, xpath, extract, tr

my aim is to extract data from the table at this website : https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-start-stromsgodset-rid1106841.html

Data are stored in tr balise, after import all tr balise thanks to xpath I check the number of elements to the 3 first rows but It is empty. If my code is ok I should have [6 6 6]

Here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf­-8 ­-*-

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-start-stromsgodset-rid1106841.html'

#Create a handle , page, to handle the contents of the first soccer game
page = requests.get(url)

#Store the contents of the website under doc
doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)

#Parse data that are stored between <tr>..</tr> of HTML
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')

#Check the length of the first 3 rows
a = [len(T) for T in tr_elements[:3]]
print(a)
```

Here is the output :

```
hao@hao-ThinkPad-T420:~$ ./extractodds.py 
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your XPath expression. You have to select `tr` elements from the table with :

```
//table[@id="TableCoteHistory"]//tr[@class and @role]
```

Output : 11 elements of length 6.